# Twitter GET Users/Search with multiple parameters

Tags: api, twitter, sttwitterapi

Can I make an API call with two or more of these parameters? Such as full name AND location.

The Twitter Get Users/Search API:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search

"Provides a simple, relevance-based search interface to public user accounts on Twitter. Try querying by topical interest, full name, company name, location, or other criteria. Exact match searches are not supported."

The parameter "q" is the one that allows the query.

q=location=manchester equivalent q=location%3Dmanchester works.

q=name=benjamin equivalent to q=name%3Dbenjamin works.

Need to know if there is a way to put those together. I am wondering if they have made 1 parameter at a time to prevent the exact match case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple combinations are not possible with this API endpoint.

Comment: No this is not available